# Parse: TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined at main.js:7:37

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform, runtime-error

I am trying to save a ParseObject with a server-created field of "arrWords". However, I keep getting an error of

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined at main.js:7:37
```

This error occurs both on my server-side code using the Parse provided SDK **and** in the Parse Dashboard when entering the value

```
["test","test2"]
```

for the arrWords array.

My code is simple:

```
$query = new \Parse\ParseQuery("Post");
$object = $query->first();
$object->setArray("arrWords", ["test", "test2"]);
$object->save();
```

The same errors occurs with setArray(), setAssociativeArray(), and add().

**Notes:**

- My Post table has over 900,000 rows
- Replicating the above steps on a new Object/Table works just fine (no JS error)

Is this due to the size of my table and / or a Parse system issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with Parse and how they handle large data sets. I've found a work-around from the Parse Dashboard that suits my needs for now.

1. Log in to Parse
2. Bring up the Parse Core dashboard
3. Select **Import**
4. Drag and drop a JSON file with the data to import
5. Type your Object / Table / Class
6. Wait for the import to finish. The new row will be added.

**Tips on JSON format for Parse Import**

- Official documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/data#data-import
- Official blog post: http://blog.parse.com/2013/02/25/importing-json/
- The JSON must be wrapped in `{"results": [ Objects ] }`
- Standard JSON formatting applies for the Object: `{ "field": "data", "array": ["data,"data"] }, { "field": ... }`